# Change access code to sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, ms-access

This code for randomize records work very very well with access database .. but when I try to change database at Sql server I have this error

> 'Time' is not a recognized built-in function name

My code :

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles                                  Button1.Click
    DataBase_Connection()
    Dim rows As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, rows) Then
        MsgBox("DECIMAL NUMBER NOT AVAILABLE", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())", rows)

    InfoCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, Con)
    InfoAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
    InfoTable = New DataTable()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable
End Sub
```

I try to change word `time` in sql query with `convert(time(0),getDate())` but sadly not best result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `NEWID()`:

```vb
Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY NEWID()", rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much popiandro .. it work very well .perfectly resolved

Comment: Learned something new again! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'Time' is not a in-built function in sql server please try following.

```
SELECT Top 100 ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ravi Mendpara